# document.getElementById().textContent not working with variable

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I use document.getElementById().textContent to set the "text content" to the value of a variable it doesn't work it doesn't to anything instead changing the text content to the value of the variable. It does work when I use

```
.textContent = "example";
```

but not

```
.textContent = example;
```

Here is my HTML

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="testScript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <p class="heading">Heading</p>
   <p id="TextSpace"></p>


</body>
```

Here is my JS

```
//Get users name
var name = prompt("What is you name");
//put the name in the element "text space"
document.getElementById("TextSpace").textContent = name;
```

The prompt appears but after that nothing happens

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move the script

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <p class="heading">Heading</p>
   <p id="TextSpace"></p>

   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="testScript.js"></script>
</body>
```

or add an onload handler

```
window.onload = function() {
    var name = prompt("What is you name");
    document.getElementById("TextSpace").textContent = name;
}
```

Right now the script is running before the elements in the DOM are available.
Note that `textContent` is not available in IE8 and below.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - added a brief explanation. Strange that it would work when using a string, but the only reason I can see for it not working would be that the element is not available and getElementById returns null.

Comment: the onload handler fixed it. @T.J.Crowder checking the script again the string and the prompt did not work :/ (I had the string working before, I must have changed something)

Comment: @qwertie: Yeah, I figured it was something like that. Note that using an `onload` handler is almost never a good idea. Instead, as adeneo said, move the `script` tag to the end of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag. `onload` happens **very** late in the page-load process.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting the script tag at the bottom, you can just put defer and it will work perfectly fine

```html
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="testScript.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
   <p class="heading">Heading</p>
   <p id="TextSpace"></p>


</body>
```

Comment: Here's the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) documentation on the `defer` attribute. `defer` will prevent a race condition problem unlike `async` in this scenario.